# Write notepad++ plugins in a different language

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Is it possible to write a plugin for notepad++ using a language other than C++ ? For example, Ruby or Haskell.

Comment: If it isn't directly supported, you could probably write a shim to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

There's a C# template here [NppPlugin.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/)

With the PythonScript plugin, and help from the [Python Script plugin wrapper](https://github.com/Ciantic/NppyPluginDll/tree/master/Example), you can also write plugins in Python.  I believe that due to a startup issue, the wrapper DLL must be named such that it alphabetically comes after the PythonScript.dll, but otherwise it works.

You can also write a plugin in any language that can export C style functions in a DLL, e.g. Delphi.